# System.InvalidOperationException: 'No Entity Framework provider found for the ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'System.Data.SQLite'

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, sqlite

im trying to use entity framework with SQLite i added a connection to the database and the EF models i created fine but when i query the DB i got this error

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'No Entity Framework provider found
> for the ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'System.Data.SQLite'.
> Make sure the provider is registered in the 'entityFramework' section
> of the application config file. See
> http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=260882 for more information.'

my app.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6" />
  </startup>
  <entityFramework>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderServices, System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
      <add name="SQLite Data Provider (Entity Framework 6)" invariant="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for SQLite (Entity Framework 6)" type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderFactory, System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
      <remove invariant="System.Data.SQLite" />
      <add name="SQLite Data Provider" invariant="System.Data.SQLite" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for SQLite" type="System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteFactory, System.Data.SQLite" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="mainEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SQLite.EF6;provider connection string=&quot;data source=C:\Users\faisa\source\repos\sqliteTst\sqliteTst\bin\Debug\db.db&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

and i installed the following packages
[Nuget packages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yM3gG.png)

PS:IM USING C# WINDOWS FORM APPLICATION .NET 4.6

i tried add var ensureDLLIsCopied = System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.Instance;
and change `<provider invariantName="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderServices, System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />`

to

```
<provider invariantName="System.Data.SQLite" type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderServices, System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i added both of these providers it's now working

```
<providers>
  <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
  <provider invariantName="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderServices, System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
  <provider invariantName="System.Data.SQLite" type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderServices, System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
</providers>
```

Comment: Yup, the last provider was missing from my lot. No wonder PHP is still a thing and Ruby took off. FFS.